# Trying to bind XML to a ComboBox using WinForm and C#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, exception

File Name: location.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<locations>
  <location id="1" position="Holiday" />
  <location id="2" position="Time Off" />
  <location id="3" position="Training" />
</locations>
```

I am trying to populate a combobox with the "text" from position. The id is not necessary at this time.

My C# Code

```
        var obj = XDocument.Load("location.xml");            
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "LocationPosition";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "LocationID";

        comboBox1.DataSource = obj.Descendants("location").Select(x => new
        {
            LocationPosition = x.Attribute("name").Value,
            LocationID = x.Attribute("id").Value
        }).ToList(); // Crashing here
```

The Error message says

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=CalendarSharing
  StackTrace:
```

Comment: What is `"name"` in this line? `LocationPosition = x.Attribute("name").Value`

Comment: i cant tell. The debugger wont show me the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That because there isn't any `name` attribute in that xml string.

Change `name` to `position`:

```
    var obj = XDocument.Load("location.xml");            
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "LocationPosition";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "LocationID";

    comboBox1.DataSource = obj.Descendants("location").Select(x => new
    {
        LocationPosition =x.Attribute("position").Value,
        LocationID =  x.Attribute("id").Value
    }).ToList();
```